# Визуальное построение GUI на SWING в NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

В NetBeans есть средство визуального построения GUI на SWING - Form Builder. По нему у меня 2 вопроса для тех, кто этим пользовался:

1. По умолчанию компонент таблица при создании имеет колонки одинаковой ширины, как их поменять?
2. Как сделать по невидимым компонент JLabel? setVisible не предлагать, ведь наверно можно какое-то свойство поменять, о котором я не знаю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

меняем размер первого столбца

```
jTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMinWidth(40);
```

если надо сделать, чтобы размер столбца был фиксированным, то

```
jTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(40);
```

а чем вам не нравится setVisible(true)?

Comment: а чем вам не нравится setVisible(true)?

Comment: если не ошибаюсь, там есть вкладка проперти - там есть большинство свойств, если там нету конкретно для отдельных столбцов - там точно есть возможность самому дописывать свойства к объектам